# Returning all records in a certain state with state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

How would you return a list of records in a certain state with state_machine? Something along the lines of:

```
@locked = current_user.docs.locked?
```

Cheers.

**EDIT**

It seems like `current_user.docs.with_state(:locked).all` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `current_user.docs.where(:state => "locked")` worked, I just thought there'd be a better way.